# Change color of a TreeNode depending on some condition; using tree from antd React Library

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using [Tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/) from Antd. I would like to change the color of some of the nodes in Tree from Antd(React Library), I create tree by lopping though my data.

I see that the following css from antd always overrides my inline style to a specific TreeNode. If I disable the color from the css in browser Elements, my color changes take place

Style that overrides: **.ant-tree li .ant-tree-node-content-wrapper**

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the style in the title for the TreeNode instead of TreeNode itself

```
<TreeNode
    title={
      <span
        style={{
          color: node.match === false ? "red" : "black"
        }}
      >
        {node[val]}
      </span>
    }
  />
```